# Serve files securely from OneDrive account to webapp users via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have a single OneDrive account with many files in it which we would like to share via a UI on our web application to our users, securely. These files are private and should not be accessed by any others directly.

Is there a way to facilitate this via the Graph API? I believe that there is but I am looking for some advice/assistance on the subject as I am not familiar with the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grant the application the permissions and access the files.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drive/root/children
```

Here is the documentation detailing the required permissions, `Files.Read.All` being the least privileged.

[Microsoft Graph - Drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)